# Can’t find the new Code First Entity Framework Database

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

Basically I am using the Entity Framework Code First technique.   The code I wrote works.  However, I can’t find the newly created database in SQL Server Management Studio.  Where is it?  What IDE should I be using to see the newly created database and tables.
I ran the following code with no problem:
IsoLocationContext db = new IsoLocationContext();

```
   Address address = new Address();

   address.TrackingNumber = "123";

   db.Addresses.Add(address);
   db.SaveChanges();
```

However, I can’t seem to find the database and tables. I did tried to refresh the list of databases.
I then added the following the line just to make sure the data was actually going to the database.

```
   IList<Address> addresses = db.Addresses.ToList();
```

The above processing worked as well. 
I also stopped and started the server and rebooted the whole machine.  Just to make sure the data wasn’t being stored in memory.  Everything worked as expected. 
I also ran the Profiler against the server while I was running the app and I saw no entries in the Trace.

Please tell me, what I am missing.  This is driving me crazy.

Also I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer / Client version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try looking at your connection string like this:

```
 ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Connection.ConnectionString
```

Comment: Thanks that pointed me in the right direction. 
It is writing to SQL Express. I honestly didn't think I had SQL Express on my machine. But, I guess my VS 2010 install installed it.  
Another thing is odd is that I did specify a connection string which is not SQL Express. I guess Code First ignores the connection string. 
You helped me resolve my issue, now I have to figure out how I can get the app to write to the database I want.

Comment: When you make your DbContext class, you can specify a connection string in your base class constructor. Something like `public class MyDbContext : DbContext { public MyDbContext() : base("Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;"){ } }`

Comment: MSDN documentation says that SQLEXPRESS always takes precedence if it is installed. I have it installed, but the database was created under (localdb)\mssqllocaldb and I was unable to find it. Running VS 2013 on Win 8.1.